# Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.

Tags: angularjs

I'm following a tutorial from pluralsight with Angular fundamentals.

I think my error has something to do with this code:

```
   import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
   import { EventService } from "./shared/event.service";
   import { ToastrService } from '../common/toastr.service'
   import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

   @Component({
       selector:'events-list',
       template:`
       <div>
           <h1> Upcoming Angular 2 Events </h1>

           <hr/>
           <div class="row">
              <div  *ngFor="let event of events"  class="col-md-5">
           <event-thumbnail (click)="handleThumbnailClick(event.name)" [event] = "event"> </event-thumbnail> 
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       `
    })

    export class EventListComponent implements OnInit{
        events:any
        constructor(private eventService:EventService, private toastr:ToastrService, private route:ActivatedRoute) {


        }
        ngOnInit() {
             this.events = this.route.snapshot.data['events']
        }   

        handleThumbnailClick(eventName)
        {
            this.toastr.success(eventName)
        }
    }
```

I tried using events:any[] but a had the same error.
I even tried in my ngOnInit() method something like this.route.snapshot.data['events'] without using this.events

Comment: Does  `this.route.snapshot.data['events']` return an array?

Comment: yes, it should return an array.

Comment: You have to define `events`as `events:any[]` because `*ngFor needs an Iterable

Comment: did the answer help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the events array and make sure  **`this.route.snapshot.data['events']`** returns an array,

```
events:any = [];
```